# Different results from lmList() and lme()

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am using mixed effects model to study the effect of plant density on profit margins. This study was conducted at 25 different site-years with 2 replications at each site-year. I used lme() to construct mixed effects model with random intercept and random slopes and, then also used lmList() to construct similar  kind of model. But the regression coefficients extracted from the two models are very different from each other. Why is this so?
Also, I need to extract p-values associated with each of the siteyear.Below is my R-script,
Note that, A=plant density and C= profit margin

```
> mod1<-lme(C~A+I(A^2),data=data2,random=~1+A+I(A^2)|Siteyear/Block)

 > coef(mod1)
 (Intercept)         A        I(A^2)
1/1   5888.03683 0.4271145 -2.843410e-06
1/2   5882.68153 0.4270284 -2.845655e-06
2/1   -735.41194 0.4155442 -2.579524e-06
2/2   -743.61149 0.4154639 -2.581391e-06
3/1     32.31468 0.4162582 -2.374211e-06
3/2     19.63991 0.4161568 -2.376277e-06
4/1   2875.50929 0.4241502 -2.967710e-06
4/2   2881.02617 0.4242170 -2.965491e-06
5/1   2347.97141 0.4188137 -2.542048e-06
5/2   2342.20967 0.4187097 -2.546271e-06

>mod2<-lmList(C~A+I(A^2)|Siteyear/Block,data=data2)
> coef(mod2)
 (Intercept)            A        I(A^2)
1/1   -1235.2661  0.641904903 -4.344950e-06
1/2   27644.4095 -0.203082000  1.460755e-06
2/1    5815.2879  0.176179646 -4.886561e-07
2/2   -5575.0247  0.506107030 -2.979219e-06
3/1    -810.7184  0.439248751 -2.464648e-06
3/2   -1542.1708  0.404386641 -2.046230e-06
4/1  -42403.0384  1.656716894 -1.100091e-05
4/2  -21815.5974  1.093547540 -7.261629e-06
5/1   20009.0521 -0.046977467  3.611271e-07
5/2   10798.8474  0.170534083 -9.115139e-07
```

Thanks in advance.